# "UseRWHlinkNavigation" blocking excel hyperlink to open in browser

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I tried to open some web hyperlinks in excel using a macro. My browser is Google Chrome. All worked well for the first time but suddenly stopped.

I tried it then manually, to click links, but when I click on a hyperlink in Excel, I get the following error:

> "Unable to open https://www.my_clicked_link.. . Cannot download the information you requested."

I found that in RegEdit (Registry Editor), under this address `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Internet` there is a key `UseRWHlinkNavigation` of the type `REG_SZ` and **with my clicked link as the value**.
I deleted the value (the link) and it worked the first time, but later it blocked again and this method is not working anymore.

I tried also
this solution:
[Error message when selecting hyperlink in Office: "Cannot locate the Internet server or proxy server"](https://learn.microsoft.com/hr-HR/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/cannot-locate-server-when-click-hyperlink)
but it worked only for the first time, and later not anymore.

Does somebody have an idea why every solution worked only for the first time but then stopped, and what could be the proper solution?

Answer (score 0):

You might have already found an answer, but I was having a similar issue and also tried the solution you reference to no avail. However, I came across the following: [Open Hyperlinks with VBA and Shell Function](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/42fbea0d-3977-480f-a4c3-6093e34f469d/open-a-web-page-with-vba).

This worked for me as I was trying to display a message box in Excel and allow the user to follow the link to a record if they hit the "Yes" button. Essentially, my solution ended up looking like:

```
Sub openURL()
    Dim targetURL as String

    targetURL = "https://www.google.com"

    result = MsgBox("Record created. View this record now?", vbYesNo)

    If result = vbYes Then
    Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -url" & targetURL)
    End If
End Sub
```

By utilizing Shell to open the hyperlink, I no longer see the URL ending up in my registry under UseRWHlinkNavigation and the error about not being able to download the content is gone.

Comment: No, I still did not find an answer until now. The only solution was to wait, after a few hours or the next day it would work again. Thanks a lot for this info! I will try it and tell you if it works.